# Using embOS functions within USB ISR for LPC1788

Tags: c, usb, microcontroller, rtos, lpc

I'm developing software for an NXP LPC1788 microcontroller, and I'm using the embOS RTOS. Whenever a message is received over USB, I want to use the OS_PutMailCond() function to store the USB message in a mailbox which a handler function is waiting on. In other words, I want to make message handling interrupt-driven.

The embOS user manual can be found [here](http://www.segger.com/cms/admin/uploads/productDocs/UM01001_embOS_Generic.pdf). Page 145 describes the OS_PutMailCond() function.

Whenever a USB message is received, it triggers the USB interrupt service routine on the LPC, but to let embOS know that it's an ISR I have to place OS_EnterInterrupt() and OS_LeaveInterrupt() at the start and end of the ISR respectively. This is necessary if I want to call embOS functions within it, including OS_PutMailCond().

The problem is that if I put OS_EnterInterrupt()/OS_LeaveInterrupt() anywhere within the USB ISR, the USB stops functioning properly and Windows informs me that the device has malfunctioned.

I have no idea why this is the case. We've tried something similar for handling messages over CAN, as shown below, and it works fine.

```
void CAN_IRQHandler(void)
{   
  OS_EnterInterrupt();

  ...

  if (MBfieldCANframeInitialised)
    OS_PutMailCond (&MBfieldCANframe, &recMessage);
  OS_LeaveInterrupt();
}
```

OS_EnterInterrupt() and OS_LeaveInterrupt() are described on pages 252 and 253 of the linked manual. From the additional information section of the former:

> If OS_EnterInterrupt() is used, it should be the first function to be
> called in the interrupt handler. It must be used with
> OS_LeaveInterrupt() as the last function called. The use of this
> function has the following effects, it:
>
> - disables task switches
> - keeps interrupts in internal routines disabled

**EDIT**

I've investigated further and found out that using OS_EnterInterrupt() and OS_LeaveInterrupt() within the USB ISR (and other ISR's like the one for the GPIO when a rising or falling edge is detected on a pin) causes an OS error. The error value is 166, which means "OS-function called from ISR with high priority".

I'll update if I find out anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It turns out the guy that made this work for the CAN ISR changed the code of one of the embOS source files to set the CAN ISR priority level from 0 to 29 (higher level = lower priority). I did the same thing for the USB ISR:

```
void OS_InitHW(void) {
  OS_IncDI();
  //
  // We assume, the PLL and core clock was already set by the SystemInit() function
  // which was called from the startup code
  // Therefore, we don't have to initailize any hardware here,
  // we just ensure that the system clock variable is updated and then
  // set the periodic system timer tick for embOS.
  //
  SystemCoreClockUpdate();                             // Update the system clock variable (might not have been set before)
  if (SysTick_Config (OS_PCLK_TIMER / OS_TICK_FREQ)) { // Setup SysTick Timer for 1 msec interrupts
    while (1);                                         // Handle Error
  }
  //
  // Initialize NVIC vector base address. Might be necessary for RAM targets or application not running from 0
  //
  NVIC_VTOR = (OS_U32)&__Vectors;
  //
  // Set the interrupt priority for the system timer to 2nd lowest level to ensure the timer can preempt PendSV handler
  //
  NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, (1u << __NVIC_PRIO_BITS) - 2u);

  NVIC_SetPriority(CANActivity_IRQn, (1u << __NVIC_PRIO_BITS) - 3u);
  NVIC_SetPriority(CAN_IRQn, (1u << __NVIC_PRIO_BITS) - 3u);
  NVIC_SetPriority(USB_IRQn, (1u << __NVIC_PRIO_BITS) - 3u);

  OS_COM_INIT();
  OS_DecRI();
}
```

I found this in the embOS documentation:

> **Why can a high priority ISR not use the OS API ?**
>
> embOS disables low priority interrupts when embOS data structures are modified. During this time high priority ISR are enabled. If they would call an embOS function, which also modifies embOS data, the embOS data structures would be corrupted.